# Deform a mesh with another mesh (in animation)

Tags: rigging, shape-keys, soft-body, surface-deform

The character I’m trying to rig has a huge collar, which needs to be displaced by her head.
If the head would only be able to move in four directions I could easily create the effect using shape keys and link them to the bones, but since the head needs to be moved in all directions I’m pretty much out of ideas.
Unfortunately softbody simulations would in this case probably create more problems than they solve.

[image: In my example the head is represented by a cylindar, since it’s pretty much it’s shape]

[image: The outcome I would love to achieve (created using a shape key)]

Comment: If you want to rig the character why don't you just control the collar part with a (neck) bone?

Comment: I already do, but with only one bone I can't get a somehow realistic deformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around with it a bit more I found a solution. I thought I could share it for someone else with a similar problem:

I deformed the collar to it's maximal deformation using a lattice. It orients itself to the neck bone rotation using a Locked Track constraint. The amount is controlled by a driver, which uses the X and Y rotation of the bone.

[image: the solution]

Here you can see the driver settings

[image: driver settings]

And here you can access the blend file

[image]

Comment: nice, could you please share the file so that we can see how it works? I wonder how you make the neck deform the lattice

Comment: I've added the file at the end of the post you replied to

Comment: oh ok thank you, I'll try to understand your setup

Comment: By the way the lattice doesn't get distorted by the neck. I distorted it manually. The neck bone just controls the orientation and the distortion amount of the lattice

Comment: ooh ok interesting